# Safari on IPad 2 input file strange behavior

Tags: ipad, input, safari

I have one `<input id="foo" type="text">` and one `<input type="file">` in a HTML page. I know that the input file is greyed in IPad 2 because it is not supported.

However what I find realy strange is that I can not set the value of "foo" e.g. `document.getElementById("foo").value='something';`

If I remove the input file, then everything works fine.

Is this a known issue/bug or am I missing something? I really find this a strange behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't there a missing closing tag in the HTML?

Comment: @bmargulies Read the question? "If I remove the input file, then everything works fine."